# Can we appeal a refusal of Schengen visa?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, iranian-citizens

My father was refused a visa to visit my brother and his newborn son, my father's grandchild, based on not having enough ties to this country of citizenship (Iran).  He would like to contest this as he has travelled to the USA and to many European countries and he never overstayed his tourist/visit visa.

Is there some sort of human rights law that we can mention in the appeal letter on the basis of being deprived from seeing his son and his new grandchild?

Comment: What was the actual refusal reason? What country did he apply to?

Comment: No, there is no such a human right as to be granted a Schengen entry visa.

Comment: You shouldn't post additional information as an answer. Regarding your questions, siblings are not very strong ties to a homeland. The best would be a stable, well-paid job or a pension, and owning a house or the like.

Answer (score 4):

You can appeal and you can reapply. Appeals rarely work, unless the visa official made a math error with the available funds or the like.

- An appeal might make sense if you think that your documents have been misinterpreted.
- A new application might make sense if you want to try again with additional documents.

If your brother is still an Iranian citizen, he has a right to travel to Iran and meet his father there. A right to a family reunification residence permit for the Schengen area applies mostly to spouses and minor children. There are a few cases where parents can get such a visa, but they require exceptional hardship.